# Left join Count disturbing left join SUM

Tags: mysql, sql

When i added a left join for getting count of foreign table, its multiply my sum value of other left join table with the count, also I cant use distinct sum here as two values can be same:

```
SELECT c.id as company_id, SUM(ct.amount) as total_billed, count(l.id) as load_count
FROM tbl_companies c
LEFT JOIN tbl_company_transactions ct ON c.id = ct.company_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_loads l ON c.id = l.company_id
GROUP BY c.id;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: @Tony its as simple as main primary table is companies, one company can have multiple loads and multiple transactions, I want sum of all transactions by each company and count of all loads by each company

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gordon's answer is more scalable but for this specific query you only need one subquery — which may also offer a performance boost since joins on the pre-aggregated data may not be able to use indexes.

```
SELECT c.id as company_id, SUM(ct.amount) as total_billed, l.load_count
FROM tbl_companies c
    LEFT JOIN tbl_company_transactions ct ON c.id = ct.company_id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT company_id, count(*) as load_count
        FROM tbl_loads
        GROUP BY company_id
    ) l ON c.id = l.company_id
GROUP BY c.id;
```

The important thing to grasp is that if you need results of an aggregate function like `SUM()` or `COUNT()`, you need to be careful when you perform more than one join with multiple rows.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pre-aggregate the data:

```
SELECT c.id as company_id, ct.total_billed,  
       l.load_count
FROM tbl_companies c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT ct.company_id, SUM(ct.amount) as total_billed
      FROM tbl_company_transactions ct
      GROUP BY ct.company_id
     ) ct
     ON c.id = ct.company_id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT l.company_id, COUNT(*) as load_count
      FROM tbl_loads l
      GROUP BY l.company_id
     ) l
     ON c.id = l.company_id;
```

As you have observed, the `JOIN` multiplies the number of rows and affects the aggregations.

Answer (score 1):

You could isolate aggregate statistics and join results afterwards.

```
WITH 
tranStats AS (
    SELECT company_id, SUM(amount) AS total_billed
    FROM tbl_company_transactions
    GROUP BY company_id
),
loadStats AS (
    SELECT company_id, COUNT(1) AS load_count
    FROM tbl_loads
    GROUP BY company_id
)
SELECT id, total_billed, load_count
FROM tbl_companies c
LEFT JOIN tranStats t ON t.company_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN loadStats l ON l.company_id = c.id
```

Comment: This is a correct answer, but is dependent on the version of MySQL the OP is using.